# Reverse enumerate to filter out similar objects in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of `CLLocations`. My goal is to find the last position in the array with the same location as the following locations, then remove all the following objects.

Example:

```
[lat: 11.123, long: 11.123,
lat: 12.345, long: 123.123,
lat: 14.124, long: 14.124,
lat: 16.1661, long: 16.1616,
lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515,
lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515, //Remove
lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515] //Remove
```

I would like to mutate the array they are stored in, instead of creating a new one.

My attempt so far:

```
 var reversedLocations = Array(locations.reverse())
            for (index,location) in reversedLocations.enumerate() {
                if index+1 <= reversedLocations.count-1 {
                    let distanceToNext = LocationInterface.sharedInterface.distanceBetweenLocations(first: location, last: locations[index+1])
                    if distanceToNext < 10 {
                        reversedLocations.removeAtIndex(reversedLocations.indexOf(location)!)
                        toDate = reversedLocations.first!.timestamp
                    }
                }
            }
```

But this code is confusing, and I'm not sure its the best way to do it. The function is just a mess, as I mutate the array im enumerating so the index isn't correct. Are there any of the Array.reduce, .sort, .map or similar who can help me out with this one?

Comment: are you sure that's an array?

Comment: The example is not a syntax-correct array, no. I typed that one in myself. The locations are in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var locations = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3]

while !locations.isEmpty && locations.dropLast().last == locations.last
{
    locations.removeLast()
}

print(locations)
```

Using `Map`, `Reduce`, or `Filter` is not necessary, in fact it would be recommended not to use them in this case. because you should stop reading all the elements once you find an element different from the last.

And like @Eendje said :

> the other answers will also remove any other duplicates other than the
>   last ones

The solution the OP used:

```
                while !locations.isEmpty && (LocationInterface.sharedInterface.distanceBetweenLocations(first: locations.dropLast().last!, last: locations.last!) > 15)
```

Comment: Nice use of `dropLast` here. I didn't like my answer since it requires too many steps, your's looks much better.

Comment: Beautiful implementation. Will try to tweak this to accept some inaccuracy, and accept your solution if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have an array of `CLLocation` then it will probably look like this

```
let locations: [CLLocation] = [
    CLLocation(latitude: 11.123, longitude: 11.123),
    CLLocation(latitude: 12.345, longitude: 123.123),
    CLLocation(latitude: 14.124, longitude: 14.124),
    CLLocation(latitude: 16.1661, longitude: 16.1616),
    CLLocation(latitude: 15.1515, longitude: 15.1515),
    CLLocation(latitude: 15.1515, longitude: 15.1515),
    CLLocation(latitude: 15.1515, longitude: 15.1515)]
```

Now we can create a `Set` like this

```
var added = Set<CLLocation>()
```

and finally filter the array

```
let filtered = locations.filter { (location) -> Bool in
    let duplicate = added.contains { (location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude) == ($0.coordinate.latitude, $0.coordinate.longitude) }
    guard !duplicate else { return false }
    added.insert(location)
    return true
}
```

Now you have your result inside `filtered`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with good time complexity, you'll need an ordered set data structure implementation. Below I show how to accomplish this with a pure Swift solution that is dependent on [the OrderedSet library](https://github.com/Weebly/OrderedSet).

If you don't mind using an NSObject subclass as your latitude & longitude pair type, you can do this with `NSOrderedSet(array:…your location objects…).array` where `…your location objects…` refers to your NSObject subclass which wraps the latitude and longitude. You'll need to implement `-hash` and `-isEqual:` to your `Location` class. That is, the principle in the example code below is very similar: you need a type that contains your latitude & longitude pairs, which is washable (override `-hash` in your NSObject subclass) and equatable (override `-isEqual:` in your NSObject).

```
import Darwin
import SortedSet

struct Location:Hashable {
    let lat:Double
    let long:Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        // This is a *terrible* hash function.
        // You'll find instructions from elsewhere for more performant ones. 
        return Int(ceil(lat + long))
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Location, rhs: Location) -> Bool {
    return lhs.lat == rhs.lat && lhs.long == rhs.long
}


let orderedLocations = OrderedSet<Location>(sequence: [Location(lat: 11.123, long: 11.123),
                                                        Location(lat: 12.345, long: 123.123),
                                                        Location(lat: 14.124, long: 14.124),
                                                        Location(lat: 16.1661, long: 16.1616),
                                                        Location(lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515),
                                                        Location(lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515),
                                                        Location(lat: 15.1515, long: 15.1515)])

for location in orderedLocations {
    print(location) // prints out the locations in the original order, with duplicates removed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let lastIndex = array.count - 1

if array[lastIndex] == array[lastIndex - 1] {
array.removeLast()
}
```

something like that would work. You might have to tweak it to fit your particular need.

*edit - these other solutions look more complicated, perhaps i misunderstood what you need